# resizing vector in cpp

Tags: c++, vector, resize

Is there a cheap way to resize a vector V from the start and not the end. Such that the resulting vector W looks like this:

V = 1,2,3,4

W = 2,3,4

Copying is a bad solution when the stored data in the vector is very long. I wonder if any better solution exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a `deque` instead of a `vector`, since it's designed to efficiently add and remove from both ends.

If for some reason you're stuck with a vector, then you're also stuck with being inefficient. No way around it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no easy way to do that: vectors grow and shrink only at the back end. However, if you wrap a vector and you wish to use only its part in calculations, you could store the offset into the vector, and pass `std::next(v.begin(), offset)` in place of the plain `begin()`:

```
vector<int> v {1,2,3,4};
size_t offset = 1;
ostream_iterator<int> out_it(std::cout,", ");
copy(next(v.begin(), offset), v.end(), out_it);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/KIy6Ms)

The issue with this approach is that the memory for elements 0..offset-1 are not released back to execution environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector that supports move semantics, can use a `move_iterator` to create a new vector from the old one with the help of a `std::move_iterator`:

```
vector<Foo> moved_vector(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()+1),
                         std::make_move_iterator(v.end()));
```

Here we assume that `Foo` is a movable type.

Note that in the case of PODs, moving is the same as copy-ing, so you don't save anything. But for e.g. `std::string`, the above makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The best that you have is `std::vector::erase` which would do a copy (move if applicable) of remaining elements:

```
V.erase(V.begin());
```